# How to use sumif with arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am having trouble with arrayformula.

I have some data at Col A & B, SUMIF($A$2:$A2,"ABC",$B$2:$B2) works perfectly fine, but I'd like to use arrayformula so I don't have to drag down the formula.

But using ArrayFormula(SUMIF($A$2:$A2,$C$1,$B$2:$B2)) doesn't do anything at all, is there any way I can make it work? I have no idea how.

[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option (say, in E2):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF(ROW(A2:A)*IF(A2:A="ABC",1,9^9),"<="&ROW(A2:A),B2:B)))`

**How It Works:**

`IF(A2:A="",,` means "If a row in A2:A is blank, do nothing for that row."

`ROW(A2:A)*IF(A2:A="ABC",1,9^9)` will create a number based on the row number at each row: the row number itself multiplied by 1 for rows matching "ABC" (resulting in the row number again, since anything times 1 is itself) or multiplied by `9^9` (i.e., some enormous number, which will be the result of for all rows that are *not* "ABC").

This will be matched against the condition `"<="&ROW(A2:A)`. So only rows at or before "each row" that matched "ABC" will deliver results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The formula works perfectly fine, now I just need to study the formula to understand it.

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for marking as "Best Answer." It lets other volunteers here know at a glance which issues have been resolved, and it helps future site visitors more easily find answers to their own similar questions or issues.

Answer (score 0):

try in E2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="ABC",MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))), 
 INDIRECT("B2:B"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0),))
```

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but it doesn't seem to working, I'm getting the incorrect result: 50, 60, 120, 150, 230, 300.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It's working as intended now, the only difference between erik's and your answer is that erik's answer will populate every single row, and yours will leave unchanged value with blank cells. Both are useful in different situations, thanks again!